# Parse String of format like "Thu Feb 02 13:28:04 CET 2017" to Date

Tags: java, date, parsing

I am facing an issue in parsing a string to date format.

I have a string `Thu Feb 02 13:28:04 CET 2017` and want to parse it as date.

I have tried several formats according to the `SimpleDateFormat` class from [this reference](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/), and my code is

```
dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
dateFormat.parse("Thu Feb 02 13:28:04 CET 2017");
```

Unfortunately, I always get unparsable text, and I can't figure out what cause this issue, although I have tried several formats like `EEE` instead of `E` or `ZZZ` instead of `Z` and`H` instead of `HH` etc...

I know there are a lot of questions on this regards, but I have tried them all without hope.

Comment: What kind of TimeZone is CET??

Comment: could be a locale issue. Your date is in English, and you don't give a locale to your SimpleDateFormat, so if your default locale is not English, it won't work.

Comment: @ShayHaned Google not working where you are?

Comment: @njzk2 Google didn't work for the guy who posted the question?? Was that a Crime to ask?

Comment: @ShayHaned not a crime, of course. Just a little surprising.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. Parsing date-times with locale and the Unparseable exception have been covered many hundreds of times already.

Answer (score 1):

Your default locale differs from the `Locale.ENGLISH`. This should work fine:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = dateFormat.parse("Thu Feb 02 13:28:04 CET 2017");
```